# Data not Printing on JLabel contained in a JPanel after clicking a Jbutton

Tags: java

I am creating a JFrame holding a JPanel(p1) and a JButton(b1)....p1 contains another JPanel(sub1) holding a JLabel(l1)...after i Click on b1,i want a String to be printed in the JLabel...but it is not printing anything.
Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class panAccDel implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton b1;
    JLabel l1;
    String intro = "Hello there";
    JPanel sub1,p1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        panAccDel panAccDel = new panAccDel();
    }
    public panAccDel(){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p1 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Print Data");
        sub1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(sub1);
        p1.add(b1);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        sub1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        l1 = new JLabel();
        sub1.add(l1);
        frame.add(p1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700,700);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == b1){
            l1.setText(intro);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a trial Code.
Any Suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listener needs added to the button. For example:

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
```